# Dual cell charging

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, power-electronics

I am using GS7001B dual cell charging IC. The schematic I used is as shown below with layout image. With this I got output voltage of 11.8V when supplied 12 volt at the input. But according to the datasheet the max output voltage is 8.4 volt. [image: Schematic]

[image: Layout design]

In case of PMOS and diode it is not specified in datasheet so I have used CJ3401 PMOS, which is LCSC part no. and S320F diode. For bypass 22uF 16V electrolytic cap.
Also I need to know about Rset register. How much value is good. According to datasheet Rset = .5 ohm for trickle charge.

Comment: Can you provide a datasheet link? What charge current limit is expected here?

Comment: If you report all the critical pin voltages in IC, it will be easier to resolve FET https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811052004_Jiangsu-Changjing-Electronics-Technology-Co---Ltd--CJ3401_C13799.pdf  IC https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202132030_SHOUDING-GS7001B-84_C2842320.pdf

Comment: Is It possible the chip was damaged during installation? perhaps from excessive temp duration or ESD.

Comment: For the next test I have used the new IC, so the chances of IC being damaged is minimum.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with the Rset value, in the datasheet it states that

\$R_{SET}=\frac{V_{CS}}{I_{O(REG)}}\$

where \$I_{O(REG)}\$ is the desired charging current and \$V_{CS}\$ is the voltage drop across \$R_{SET}\$. According to the datasheet the voltage drop is typically 200mV, so \$R_{SET}\$ can be chosen based on what charge current you want.

**This next part is likely incorrect, see the below comment chain**

This leads to a possible answer for the original question. You observe a 200mV drop from \$V_{IN}\$ to \$V_{OUT}\$ which is caused by the resistor. Since there is no battery to charge the output current is 0A (or close too) which means the 11.8V can develop on \$V_{OUT}\$ but once a battery is attached for charging the voltage will drop as a constant current is fed to the battery.

Comment: the 200 mV drop is not to Vout but to CS

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the datasheet but it says that 'The GS7001B monitors charge current at the CS input by the voltage drop across a sense-resistor, RSET, in series with the battery pack'. Does that not mean that RSET is also in series with the battery which would cause the 11.8V build up while no battery is attached? (i.e. 0.2V drop on RSET leads to a 11.8V drop across the multimeter)

Comment: What about the status leds at this condition. Both the leds should blink, isn't it? But the first led was constantly glowing with no load.

Comment: Initially I have used AP2301B PMOS and RB521S-30 diode. Without load status leds were blinking. Output voltage was fluctuating between 4 to 6.5 V. With load connected, status led of Charging glow but smoke from the circuit appeared. Then I replace the diode with S320F. Still the smoke appeared and then I replaced transistor with Cj3401. Without the transistor only charging status LED was blinking.

Comment: @rs04 is there any condition where the LEDs blink? or is LED1 always on and LED2 always off? (I'm mostly wondering if it changes when VOUT is being measured)

also where was the smoke coming from?

Comment: In case of Battery temperature monitoring section in the datasheet,  for cold and high temp voltages are .5V and 2.4V. When I checked the voltage of TS pin it appeared to 0. Externally pulled up using 100k resistor to make its voltage to around 1.2V does not work as well. Does the datasheet means the TS pin voltage should be between .5 to 2.4 V for operation or what?

Comment: Without PMOS connection LED1 was blinking.

Comment: you misread the schematic in the datasheet. It's  incorrect as you stated. Cs is a high side sense with 200 mV =/-10% / 0.5ohms = 0.4A thus it shouldonly read 11.8V on CS not the output

Comment: I found smoke coming from DIODE for the first time and the from PMOS with diode replaced and 2cell load was connected.

Comment: There is now a short internal between CS and Vout if both are 11.8V  blown cicuit perhaps from backwards Zener, now the chip is blown

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 So this is a misprint in the datasheet then? I'll edit my answer in that case. 

@ rs04 can you check continuity between CS and VOUT on the chip you are using, and if you have an extra chip check that as well to see if it's different

Comment: No it's a misprint in your answer. Pls delete it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7coeH.png

Comment: Without an internal schematic of the chip (or physical access) it's impossible to say whether or not it is connected internally, given this statement from the datasheet (page 7 second to last paragraph) '[The chip] monitors charge current at the CS input by the voltage drop across a sense-resistor, RSET, in series with the battery pack.' it appears it might be